# Is it possible to use latest triton server version on older version of cuda driver (470) by using cuda-compat 12.1?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, nvidia, onnx, triton

For some reason, I didn't update the cuda driver version of my environment, currently using 470.42.01

But I wanted to use the latest triton-influence-server（23.04, Requires NVIDIA CUDA 12.1.0 by default, so I tried something like this:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:23.04-py3
COPY cuda-compat /cuda-compat
RUN dpkg -i /cuda-compat/cuda-compat-12-1_530.30.02-1_amd64.deb
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-12.1/compat:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Then build an image and run.

Got an error that looks like it's not supported, I don't know if there's something wrong with my approach, or is it just not supported?

```
ERROR: The NVIDIA Driver is present, but CUDA failed to initialize.  GPU functionality will not be available.
   [[ System has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination (error 803) ]]
W0520 02:02:08.644624 1 pinned_memory_manager.cc:236] Unable to allocate pinned system memory, pinned memory pool will not be available: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
E0520 02:02:08.644693 1 server.cc:230] Failed to initialize CUDA memory manager: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
W0520 02:02:08.644699 1 server.cc:237] failed to enable peer access for some device pairs
I0520 02:02:08.650682 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: densenet_onnx:1
I0520 02:02:08.650712 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: inception_graphdef:1
I0520 02:02:08.650734 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: simple_int8:1
I0520 02:02:08.650753 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: simple_sequence:1
I0520 02:02:08.650771 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: simple:1
I0520 02:02:08.650791 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: simple_dyna_sequence:1
I0520 02:02:08.650812 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: simple_identity:1
I0520 02:02:08.650854 1 model_lifecycle.cc:459] loading: simple_string:1
I0520 02:02:08.651782 1 onnxruntime.cc:2504] TRITONBACKEND_Initialize: onnxruntime
I0520 02:02:08.651801 1 onnxruntime.cc:2514] Triton TRITONBACKEND API version: 1.12
I0520 02:02:08.651806 1 onnxruntime.cc:2520] 'onnxruntime' TRITONBACKEND API version: 1.12
I0520 02:02:08.651811 1 onnxruntime.cc:2550] backend configuration:
{"cmdline":{"auto-complete-config":"true","backend-directory":"/opt/tritonserver/backends","min-compute-capability":"6.000000","default-max-batch-size":"4"}}
E0520 02:02:08.663226 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'densenet_onnx' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
I0520 02:02:08.883231 1 tensorflow.cc:2565] TRITONBACKEND_Initialize: tensorflow
I0520 02:02:08.883260 1 tensorflow.cc:2575] Triton TRITONBACKEND API version: 1.12
I0520 02:02:08.883265 1 tensorflow.cc:2581] 'tensorflow' TRITONBACKEND API version: 1.12
I0520 02:02:08.883269 1 tensorflow.cc:2605] backend configuration:
{"cmdline":{"auto-complete-config":"true","backend-directory":"/opt/tritonserver/backends","min-compute-capability":"6.000000","default-max-batch-size":"4"}}
E0520 02:02:08.883301 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'simple_int8' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
E0520 02:02:08.883308 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'inception_graphdef' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
E0520 02:02:08.883314 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'simple' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
E0520 02:02:08.883334 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'simple_identity' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
E0520 02:02:08.883333 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'simple_sequence' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
E0520 02:02:08.883347 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'simple_dyna_sequence' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
E0520 02:02:08.883365 1 model_lifecycle.cc:597] failed to load 'simple_string' version 1: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination

I0520 02:02:08.883525 1 server.cc:610]
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Backend     | Path                                                            | Config                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| onnxruntime | /opt/tritonserver/backends/onnxruntime/libtriton_onnxruntime.so | {"cmdline":{"auto-complete-config":"true","backend-directory":"/opt/tritonserver/backends","min-compute-capability":"6.000000","default-max-batch-size":"4"}} |
| tensorflow  | /opt/tritonserver/backends/tensorflow/libtriton_tensorflow.so   | {"cmdline":{"auto-complete-config":"true","backend-directory":"/opt/tritonserver/backends","min-compute-capability":"6.000000","default-max-batch-size":"4"}} |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I0520 02:02:08.883603 1 server.cc:653]
+----------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Model                | Version | Status                                                                                                                       |
+----------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| densenet_onnx        | 1       | UNAVAILABLE: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination |
| inception_graphdef   | 1       | UNAVAILABLE: Internal: unable to get number of CUDA devices: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination |
+----------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

W0520 02:02:08.919379 1 metrics.cc:792] Cannot get CUDA device count, GPU metrics will not be available
I0520 02:02:08.919635 1 metrics.cc:701] Collecting CPU metrics
I0520 02:02:08.919802 1 server.cc:284] Waiting for in-flight requests to complete.
I0520 02:02:08.919810 1 server.cc:300] Timeout 30: Found 0 model versions that have in-flight inferences
I0520 02:02:08.919817 1 server.cc:315] All models are stopped, unloading models
I0520 02:02:08.919823 1 server.cc:322] Timeout 30: Found 0 live models and 0 in-flight non-inference requests
error: creating server: Internal - failed to load all models
```

Comment: what GPU are you running this on?

Answer (score 1):

I see, this is the minor version number of the cuda driver that I ignored
I use the cuda driver of 470.42
But cuda-compat requires 470.57+